# Retrieving all term positions from DocsAndPositionsEnum

Tags: solr, lucene

I am upgrading to Solr 4.1 and having trouble retrieving position and offset information using the new API.  My **index** comprises of one document with one field containing the string '**one quick brown fox jumped over one lazy dog**'. I am **querying** my index for **'one'** and trying to retrieve positions and offsets corresponding to 'one'.

Here is the code snippet

```
Terms terms=reader.getTermVector(docId, fieldName);
TermsEnum termsEnum= terms.iterator(TermsEnum.EMPTY);
    BytesRef term;
    while((term=termsEnum.next())!=null){
        String docTerm = term.utf8ToString();
        DocsAndPositionsEnum docPosEnum = termsEnum.docsAndPositions(null, null, DocsAndPositionsEnum.FLAG_OFFSETS);
        //Check if the current term is the same as the query term and if so
        //retrieve all positions (can be multiple occurrences of a term in a field) corresponding to the term
        if (queryTerms.contains(docTerm)) {
            int position;
            while((position=docPosEnum.nextPosition())!=-1){
                int start=docPosEnum.startOffset();
                int end=docPosEnum.endOffset();
                //Store start, end and position in an a list
                }
        }
    }
```

The inner while loop is incorrect. Any pointers on how to iterate through all positions in a DocsAndPositionsEnum will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

Here is what worked for me

```
Terms terms=reader.getTermVector(docId, fieldName);
TermsEnum termsEnum= terms.iterator(TermsEnum.EMPTY);
BytesRef term;
while((term=termsEnum.next())!=null){
            String docTerm = term.utf8ToString();
            //Check if the current term is the same as the query term and if so
            //retrieve all positions (can be multiple occurrences of a term in a field) corresponding to the term
            if (queryTerms.contains(docTerm)) {
                DocsAndPositionsEnum docPosEnum = termsEnum.docsAndPositions(null, null, DocsAndPositionsEnum.FLAG_OFFSETS);
                docPosEnum.nextDoc();
                //Retrieve the term frequency in the current document
                int freq=docPosEnum.freq();
                for(int i=0; i<freq; i++){
                    int position=docPosEnum.nextPosition();
                    int start=docPosEnum.startOffset();
                    int end=docPosEnum.endOffset();
                    //Store start, end and position in a list
                    }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't iterating to a `Document` in your `DocsAndPositionsEnum`.

```
    if (queryTerms.contains(docTerm)) {
        docPosEnum.advance(docId)
        int freq=docPosEnum.freq();
        for(int i=0; i<freq; i++){
            int position=docPosEnum.nextPosition();
            int end=docPosEnum.endOffset();
            //Store start, end and position in an a list
        }
    }
```

You'll likely want to store the docid returned from `docPosEnum.nextDoc()`, I would guess.

Comment: You are right in that I will need to iterate to the next Document. However, the solution that you have posted will not work. The inner while will result in an infinite loop, because docPosEnumEnum.nextPosition() returns -1 only if positions were not indexed..and I have indexed the positions. Also, notice that I have the docID (line 1 of the code snippet), which makes the outer while loop unnecessary.

Comment: I didn't take that you only wanted the positions enumeration for the single document.  The way you have written it in your answer, it should, unless I'm mistaken, return the results for the first document containing the term.  The first document returned in that enumeration may not be the document indicated.  You'll want to use [advance(int)](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-BETA/core/org/apache/lucene/search/DocIdSetIterator.html#advance(int)) instead, per my updated answer.